# Why do my onclick function only work once?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple to-do list to practice javascript. That's what I manage to do so far, but now I am completely stuck. My knowledge only allows me to tweak things around, hoping that would do something.

So the problem is that I can add tasks and open the prompt window when I click on the "Edit" button, but the edit function works only with the first tasks. Hopefully, my code makes some sense. Thank you for your suggestions in advance. PS: The "Edit" function should only make the prompt window appear for now.

```js
let adding_tasks = document.getElementById('add');
let element = document.getElementById('task-container');
let entering_task;
let para;
let node;
let paraEdit;
let nodeEdit;


adding_tasks.addEventListener('click', () => {

  entering_task = window.prompt('Enter your task: ');
  para = document.createElement('p');
  para.setAttribute('id', 'tasks');
  node = document.createTextNode(entering_task);

  paraEdit = document.createElement('p');
  paraEdit.setAttribute('id', 'edit');
  nodeEdit = document.createTextNode('Edit');

  para.appendChild(node);
  element.appendChild(para);

  paraEdit.appendChild(nodeEdit);
  element.appendChild(paraEdit);

  edit.onclick = function() {
    entering_task = window.prompt('Enter your task: ', entering_task);
  };

});
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo">ToDoLIST</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<section>
  <div id="task-container" class="container">
    <h1 class="my-tasks">Your Tasks</h1>
    <img id="add" class="add-button" src="img/add_button.svg" alt="Add task">
  </div>
</section>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: `edit` is not define in `edit.onclick`. Change it with `paraEdit.onclick`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. Unfortunately, I don't get it completely, but I'll try to figure it out

Comment: It is just a typo. You do not have anything called `edit`. It is called `paraEdit` so the onclick handler needs to be assigned to the paraEdit

Comment: To be honest I thought I do - here: 
paraEdit = document.createElement('p');
paraEdit.setAttribute('id', 'edit');
It wasn't a typo because I kind of had a thought process behind it. I deleted it but before I had a line of code that grabbed "edit" by id, but then I realize it worked anyways. Of course, only once. Sorry for my mumbling, I just trying to understand why my method didn't work)

Comment: Maybe I started a project that is too complicated for me, but everyone tells me to work on actual projects. So I little bit confused about what to do

Answer (score 1):

So apart from the typo, you are missing some functionality
Also IDs need to be unique.

I chose to delegate the click on the edit, I gave the edit a class and wrapped the tasks

I also renamed some elements to be self documenting

```js
const adding_tasks = document.getElementById('add');
const container = document.getElementById('task-container');

container.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // any click in the task list 
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('edit')) { // edit was clicked
    const para = tgt.closest('div').querySelector('p');
    para.textContent = window.prompt('Edit your task: ', para.textContent);
  }
});


adding_tasks.addEventListener('click', () => {

  const entering_task = window.prompt('Enter your task: ');
  const task = document.createElement('div');
  const para = document.createElement('p');
  para.setAttribute('id', 'tasks');
  const node = document.createTextNode(entering_task);

  const paraEdit = document.createElement('p');
  paraEdit.classList.add('edit');
  const nodeEdit = document.createTextNode('Edit');
  para.appendChild(node);
  paraEdit.appendChild(nodeEdit);
  task.appendChild(para)
  task.appendChild(paraEdit);
  container.appendChild(task);
});
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo">ToDoLIST</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<section>
  <div id="task-container" class="container">
    <h1 class="my-tasks">Your Tasks</h1>
    <img id="add" class="add-button" src="img/add_button.svg" alt="Add task">
  </div>
</section>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, I know. But I had a hard time even making my edit button showing a prompt window. I didn't want to start thinking about actual editing until I solve this problem

Comment: Sorry. Now you have some code to study. Delegation is the recommended way. Clicking in the container and then see what was clicked saves the event handler on every single edit button